# Angular Material not working correctly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I am learning AngularJS and I want to use Angular Material, I've downloaded it with `npm install angular-material` and I've imported it but it is not working. That is what I see, any help please?

[image: No click]

[image: Clicked]

This is my html code

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>My store</title>
</head>
<body ng-app="tienda" ng-controller="tiendaCtrl">
    {{name}}

    <md-toolbar>
        <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
            <p><strong>My Store</strong></p>
            <md-button><md-icon class='mdi mdi-plus-circle'></md-icon>New Classified</md-button>
        </div>
    </md-toolbar>

    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular-material/angular-material.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular-aria/angular-aria.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/tienda.ctrl.js"></script>

</body>
```

This is my `app.js` file

```
var myApp = angular.module("tienda", ['ngMaterial']);

myApp.config(function($mdThemingProvider){
    $mdThemingProvider.theme('default')
        .primaryPalette('teal')
        .accentPalette('orange');
});
```

Comment: Could you try adding the scripts in the `head` instead of the `body`? And by the way, your `html` tag is not closed and you are missing a `DOCTYPE`.

Comment: Made the change but still not working, so weird. I have the html closed but don't know why it doesn't appear here, i'll try to edit.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in console

Comment: No, I just have this message "Capturing clicks"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing CSS files here. The directive works fine but the styling is not there. Have a look at [their Github](https://github.com/angular/material/tree/v1.0.5#cdn), under the CDN part, it is written what to import.

The CSS should be in your `node_modules` folder so I guess you should put this in your `head`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/angular-material/angular-material.css">
```

Answer (score 2):

**This might be what you was looking for, you need to add few lines to styles in angular.json**

> "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/pink-bluegrey.css"

This worked for me. Give a Try!